# Rapid screen capture program?

Tags: screen-capture

Are there any free cross-OS (or at least Windows) programs that will do rapid screen shots and save them as images? I'd like to create animated gifs with these.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/) (Open source) or [Snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html) (Shareware)